# PHP : array_map with exponential function not working

Tags: php, function, array-map, exp

I am trying to modify an entire associative array with a function.

This is how the array looks like:

Array ( [3] => 11 [1] => 12 [2] => 23 [0] => 34 [4] => 42 )

And this is the function:

```
$bfactor = end($fballs) * log(100); 
function bexponential($bn) {    
    return(exp($bfactor / $bn));
}

$fballs = array_map("bexponential", $fballs);
```

It first calculates a $bfactor by multiplying the last element of the array by log(100) and then calculates the exponential of that $bfactor divided by each element of the array.

The function and the array_map work with simple operators like multiplications and divisions but not with the exponential function.

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

`$bfactor` is not available within your `bexponential` function.

You need to do this:

```
$bfactor = end($fballs) * log(100); 

function bexponential($bn) { 
  global $bfactor;   
  return exp($bfactor / $bn);
}

$fballs = array_map("bexponential", $fballs);
```

Alternatively:

```
$bfactor = end($fballs) * log(100); 

function bexponential($bn) {    
  return exp($GLOBALS['bfactor'] / $bn);
}

$fballs = array_map("bexponential", $fballs);
```

Or, if you don't need the `bexponential` function anywhere else, in one go:

```
$bfactor = end($fballs) * log(100); 

$fballs = array_map(function ($bn) use ($bfactor) {
  return exp($bfactor / $bn);
}, $fballs);
```

Comment: global did the trick, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @mirix No problem, make sure to check the duplicate question to learn more about variable scopes though!